# Is this a good approach to "Obfuscate" User ID?

Tags: php, math, obfuscation

I need to provide users with a unique link that contains their `USER ID` *(please do not suggest usage of UUID etc in this case)*

It's not that important, but I still rather make sure it's very difficult to extract the user id or guess the next one etc! (even if it's achieved with security by obscurity...)

I came up with this solution:

```
// @var $id int|string
function obfuscate_number($id, bool $reverse=FALSE)
{
    $changing   = (int)substr($id, -1);
    $multiplier = '45' . $changing;
    $base       = 25;

    // Obfuscate Number
    if($reverse === FALSE)
    {
        $new     = bcmul("$id", "$multiplier", 0);
        $convert = bcadd("$new", "$changing", 0);
        $obf     = base_convert($convert, 10, $base) . $changing;

        return $obf;
    }
    // Reverse to Number
    else
    {
        $deobf   = base_convert(substr($id, 0, -1), $base, 10);
        $convert = bcsub("$deobf", "$changing", 0);

        // Simple Validation
        if($convert % $multiplier !== 0) return FALSE;

        $number  = (int)bcdiv("$convert", "$multiplier", 0);

        return $number;
    }
}

// For example number  123456 => 5dnpfi6
// After reversing    5dnpfi6 => 123456


// For example number   563 => g81h3
// After reversing    g81h3 => 563
```

If it is possible please help me improve it.

Also I think the chance of collision is 0 here, am I correct?

Comment: Why would the user ID need to be contained within this string? A suggestion would to be keep a private key on your server, and encrypt the known user ID, and share the encrypted value with the end user. When that ID is passed back to your server, you can then use your key to decrypt the value and transmute it back to the known user ID. You are essentially doing a poor-mans encryption.

Comment: @MattClark It is simply to generate invitation code, it's not that important to encrypt it!  `https://example.com/?invited_by=563` becomes `https://example.com/?invited_by=j1fk3` all I want to achieve is make it hard for people to guess valid user ids, also do not make it obvious how many users the site currently has! do you think what I've done is enough for that?

Comment: Also I need to keep it kinda short, it will be too long after encryption

Comment: There are two things you need to work out: 1. If someone does actually change the invitation code, what does your decode algorithm make of it? 2. What is the change of someone randomly guessing another user ID?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware For #1 I edited the code and added a simple validation (`if($convert % $multiplier !== 0) return FALSE;`) , in case of false it's not stored as inviter. For #2 I'm not sure have to think about it (but there is no advantage to having invite_code) it will be used for promoting etc

Comment: Given a few invitation codes it's very easy for someone to figure out they are all multiples of a certain number. You need to use proper encryption. If you're worried about the code becoming too long, use an algorithm that guarantees short output like skip32

Comment: IMO use UUID for user ids and perhaps generate shorter invite id from UUID. UUID does not give out any relevant information if it does get out.

Comment: @Joni Thanks for mentioning skip32 , I read that it is made exactly for the purpose of encrypting User ID etc.

Comment: Why not just add a column to your users table that has a GUID you can include in the link? Or have a separate table to track invitations and link it back to the user internally. That way you could have unique links for each invite.

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Solutions

#### Slow

Hashing, hashing will allow you to send the hash out and without an extremely moderate amount of computations will not be put reversed into the user id. The server would hash, send string to client, client visits webpage, you lookup in a database of some sort matching hash with user id.

#### Fast (Recommended)

Using AES encryption will allow you to encrypt data that is generally guaranteed to be unbreakable if you follow AES guidelines. So an approach would be to encrypt data with AES and convert to base 64. Send the base64 to the user and when the user clicks the link, you simply just need to convert base 64 to binary, and decrypt. I would say this is considerably faster than the hashing approach.